# wxpython thread issue with WMI

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, wmi, python-multithreading

I have a small program running all kinds of checks against WMI. 
The program is designed in wxpython. The problem is when I run the checks, the pane is freezing until all are completed. Hence I decided to look into threading. (not so clear to me and not really GOOD starter info available...so any link is welcome!). 
The problem is, when I have the function e.g. checkVersion like:

```
for computerInfo in c.Win32_OperatingSystem():
            self.midPanelsT8Result.SetLabel(computerInfo.Caption)
```

The panel is updated just fine. 
However, when I have a worker thread doing the work:

```
for computerInfo in c.Win32_OperatingSystem():
            retInfo = computerInfo.Caption
```

and later use wx.Postevent to pass on the 'retInfo'
the program is producing an error: 
*AttributeError: winmgmts:.Win32_OperatingSystem*

the variable "c" is declared on top of the program as a global

```
c = wmi.WMI()
```

no clue why it does not work in the workerthread, but does in the MainFrame as a function?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you declaring `global c` at the start of the thread?

Comment: import wmi, then c = wmi.WMI() .... outside the classes / functions...

Comment: Then declare `global c` at the start of the thread followed by `self.c = c` and then use `self.c` in the thread. It's difficult to know for sure because you haven't posted your code.